# Execute sudo command and fail to run in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When i execute the command 'sudo backup_script',the ubuntu displays 'sudo: backup_script: command not found',and i found no answers.
So i ask some useful answers.If you can help me,write your precious tips.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If it is a bash script, then try to run it like this

```
sudo bash backup_script
```